# hidden directories to ls (not dot prefixed file)

Tags: files, btrfs

I'm facing with a uncommon issue, which is:
After btrfs read failure and a `btrfs check --repair` on my partition mounted in /home, it seems that some directories have disappeared. I explain :
When I list the content of my home, some directories (e.g. ~/work) are no more listed.

```
$ ls -ia1 ~
   261 .
   256 ..
...
431144 VirtualBox VMs
338654 workspace
```

However, I can still access them:

```
$ ls -ia ~/work
4106712 .      261 ..   4522455 content
```

It seems that the inode is no more referenced :

```
$ find /home -inum 4106712
$
```

the command does not return anything.

Here are some other command outputs :

```
$ sudo btrfs inspect-internal inode-resolve 4106712 /home
/home/pef/work
```

and

```
$ stat ~/work
File: '/home/pef/work'
Size: 84              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 29h/41d Inode: 4106712     Links: 1
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1001/     pef)   Gid: ( 1001/     pef)
Access: 2016-05-19 16:01:31.480990215 +0200
Modify: 2016-05-19 16:01:26.237274459 +0200
Change: 2016-05-19 16:01:26.237274459 +0200
Birth: -
```

This issue does not only occurs on direct $HOME directory childs, but also on deeper nodes.
Is there any way to make ls command to view these files, as I don't remember all my directories/files and cannot access them by there name ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have backups and the possibility of going to a filesystem less likely to loose track of what inode links to where?

Comment: Unfortunately, it was in my todo list, but not done yet. Now, rsync does not see this ghost directories and files.